# Laravel Factory Generics With Psalm

Tags: php, laravel, psalm-php

I'm struggling to get the generic to work for the Laravel 9 factories with psalm.

Doc block:

```
/**
 * @extends Factory<Trip>
 */
class TripFactory extends Factory { ... }
```

Use case:

```
TripFactory::new()->create();
```

Error:

`InvalidTemplateParam - app/Domains/Trips/Seeders/TripSeeder.php:23:9 - Extended template param TModel of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection<int, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model> expects type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, type int given (see https://psalm.dev/183)`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was also dealing with the same issue. Which `vimeo/psalm` version are you using currently?

There's seems to be a fix for this in newer `vimeo/psalm`  releases.

I was running:

```
"vimeo/psalm": "4.23.0"
```

after upgrading to `4.30.0` ( presumably also ^5.x should be fine )

```
"vimeo/psalm": "4.30.0"
```

the issue is resolved.

I can't pinpoint it exactly but i guess it's due to the fix in [v4.25.0](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/releases/tag/v4.25.0)
which states:

> Improve inferring the "final" static type when calling static methods inside a different class by [@someniatko](https://github.com/someniatko) in [#8249](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/pull/8249)

This definitely seems to deal with this type of issue and I have to stop now because it's a deep rabbit hole ;-)